# Tengo Problemas al modificar los permisos de un archivo con C en Linux

Tags: c, linux, permisos

estoy teniendo problemas con un programa que estoy haciendo en C, el cual tiene como objetivo copiar un archivo de un directorio origen a un directorio destino, y que en medio del proceso el archivo sea copiado con los permisos modificados.

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#undef _POSIX_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){

    FILE *file1, *file2;
    int data = 0;
    
    file1 = fopen("origen/texto.txt", "r");
    file2 = fopen("destino/copia_texto.txt", "w");
    
    while ( (data = fgetc ( file1 )) != EOF ) {
        fputc ( data, file2 );
    }
    
    fclose( file1 );
    fclose( file2 );
    
    //Cambiando los permisos
    
    /* declaraciones para cambiar permisos */
    char fn[]= "destino/copia_texto.txt";
    FILE *stream;
    struct stat info;
    
    if((stream = fopen(fn, "w")) == NULL)
        perror("fopen() error");
    else{
        fclose(stream);
        stat("destino/copia_texto.txt", &info);
        printf("Los permisos originales son: %08x\n", info.st_mode);
        if (chmod(fn, info.st_mode|S_IROTH) != 0)
            perror("chmod() error");
        else {
        stat( "destino/copia_texto.txt", &info );
        printf("Ahora los permisos son: %08x\n", info.st_mode);
        }   
        unlink("destino/copia_texto.txt");
    }
}
```

Este codigo hace el trabajo de copiado correctamente, sin embargo al momento de ejecutar la función chmod pareciera modificar correctamente los permisos pero a la hora de ir a el directorio "destino" me encuentro con que el archivo desparece y no entiendo por que pasa.

Agradecería la información.

Answer (score 0):

Crep que el problema es el unlink, que borraría el ítem del File System

https://linux.die.net/man/2/unlink

Comment: Me funciono!!!!! te agradezco!

Comment: Excelente! Bienvenido a SO. La forma en la que se agradece (aparte de agradecer con un mensaje, si se quiere) es haciendo un "upvote" en la respuesta. Y si es **la respuesta** a tu pregunta, seleccionándola con el check (esto también se refleja en la lista de preguntas porque saldría como _respondida_).